# Set an object function externally that can be called internally

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to be able to set a function `onbroadcast` in `SpeechRecognition` after I create a new `SpeechRecognition` object so that I can call this function internally if certain conditions are met.

I would like to be able to set it in the same way that you would set something like `onerror` in `webkitSpeechRecognition`. When I look at `onerror` in the Developer Tools it looks like it might be done via some sort of getter/setter like what is described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters) but I can't be certain.

Is this possible?

recognition.js:

```
var SpeechRecognition = function () {
    var recognitionObject = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    recognitionObject.onresult = function (event) {
        if(event.results.length > 0) {
            if (onbroadcast !== null && onbroadcast === 'function') {
                onbroadcast('there are results');
            }
        }
    }
    recognitionObject.onerror = function (event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
    recognitionObject.onend = function (event) {
        console.log(event);
    }
    recognitionObject.start();
}

SpeechRecognition.prototype.onbroadcast = null;
```

main.js:

```
var sr = new SpeechRecognition();
sr.onbroadcast = function(msg) {
    document.getElementById('id') = msg;
}
```

Comment: `onupdateraw` and `onbroadcast` are undeclared variables, what did you mean to do with them? I suppose you want to refer to a `.onbroadcast` **property** of your `SpeechRecognition` instance - typically with `this` [but not in a callback](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/1048572) like here.

Comment: Sorry - `onupdateraw` was a typo.

Comment: I want to set `onbroadcast` from outside of the object somehow, but call it from within (if it is set)

Comment: @millarnui what do you mean by `sr.onbroadcast = function(msg) {
    document.getElementById('id') = msg;
}` ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refer to `onbroadcast` as a [**property**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Objects_and_properties) of your instance (`this.onbroadcast`). It doesn't magically become available as a variable inside the constructor scope.

```
function SpeechRecognition() {
    var self = this; // a reference to the instance
    var recognitionObject = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    recognitionObject.onresult = function (event) {
        if (event.results.length > 0 && typeof self.onbroadcast === 'function') {
            self.onbroadcast('there are results');
//              ^ a property access
        }
    };
    recognitionObject.onerror = recognitionObject.onend = function (event) {
        console.log(event);
    };
    recognitionObject.start();
}
```

Comment: "self" is a reserved word @Bergi

Comment: Immediately after I set `sr.broadcast` in main.js I can see that the property has been set but when `recognitionObject.onresult` is fired  `self.onbroadcast` === undefined.

Comment: @BekimBacaj: No it's not. It's a global variable (`window.self`), yes, but not reserved.

Comment: @millarnui: I cannot reproduce with my code. Notice that in your OP you also forgot the `typeof` keyword

Comment: @millarnui: You might want to put a `console.log(self)` in the `onresult` handler

Comment: @BekimBacaj: I'm not! It's just a local variable inside the scope of the constructor. You could've named it anything.